# How to append a existing xml file ?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, vb.net-2010

I have a xml file and I want to modified/append it by adding some nodes. 
I have written a below code

its giving an error  -

> Cannot insert a node or any ancestor of that node as a child of
>   itself.

Code-

```
            Dim xdoc1 As New XmlDocument()
           xdoc1.Load("C:\xml1.xml1")

           Dim TrialNo As XmlNode = xdoc1.CreateElement("TrialNo")

           Dim TotalNoOfTrials = GetTotalNoOfTrials()
           TrialNo.InnerText = TotalNoOfTrials + 1

           TrialNo.AppendChild(name1)

           xdoc1.Save(Path)
```

I have below existing file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
      <Data> 
      <TrialNo>1</TrialNo>
      </Data>
```

and I want to append file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
      <Data> 
      <TrialNo>1</TrialNo>
      <TrialNo>2</TrialNo>
      <TrialNo>3</TrialNo>
     </Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select root element which is Data here and then append two childs i.e. TrialNo.`

**Steps:**

```
    'Open xml file    
    Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument
    xdoc.Load("Xml1.xml")

    'Select root node
    Dim xnode As XmlNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Data")

    'Create child element TrialNo
    Dim childone As XmlElement = xdoc.CreateElement("TrialNo")
    childone.InnerText = "2"
    xnode.AppendChild(childone)

    'Create child element TrialNo
    Dim childtwo As XmlElement = xdoc.CreateElement("TrialNo")
    childtwo.InnerText = "3"
    xnode.AppendChild(childtwo)

    'Save the entries
    xdoc.Save("Xml1.xml")
```